# Material Design Lite drawer doesn't respond to scroll wheel in chrome

Tags: css, material-design-lite

I've created a very basic mdl page and I expect the drawer component to have a variable about of content, almost certainly greater than the height of the page, so it will need to be scrollable. Unfortunately, something about the mdl framework stops the mouse wheel from working on the drawer component. You can even see this in the provided samples such as http://www.getmdl.io/templates/android-dot-com/index.html

I've tried setting the z-index of the drawer div to 999 and other such hacks but it still doesn't seem to work. You can use the scroll bar but that's hardly ideal. It seems to work by default in firefox but not in chrome or IE. Has anyone else dealt with this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem will be fixed with 1.0.6.
Refere https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/pull/1652